# Adding 5 Hours in a Script to Delete Old Date Files (GAS - Google Drive)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to add 5 hours to my script, because where I look for the data, the local time is 5 hours longer than where I live. So for the date to be synchronized, I need to add.

```
function getOldFileIDs() {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
  var files = folder.getFiles();
  var today = new Date(new Date().toDateString()).getTime()+ 1000*60*60*5;
  var obj = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var dateFromFilename = file.getName().substr(0, 10);
    if (/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)) { // Here, the format of date string is checked.
      var date = new Date(dateFromFilename).getTime();
      if (date < today) {
        obj.push({id: file.getId(), date: file.getDateCreated(), owner: file.getOwner().getEmail()});
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
};

function deleteFiles() {
  var email = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com"; // Added
  var obj = getOldFileIDs(); // Modified
  obj.forEach(function(e) { // Modified
    if (e.owner == email) { // Added
      Drive.Files.remove(e.id); // Modified
    }
  });
};
´´´

today is this way, but it didn't work, I would like to know what is the failure in the form I'm trying to do
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to shift the time, which is used for comparing, by 5 hour.
- From `/\d{4}\/\d{2}\/\d{2}/.test(dateFromFilename)` in your script, it is found that only the year, month and day of the filename are compared.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the year, month and day are compared. So from the date shifted 5 hour from the current time, it is required to use the year, month and day.
- `toDateString()` retrieves the year, month and day while the time becomes `00:00:00`.

When above point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var today = new Date(new Date().toDateString()).getTime()+ 1000*60*60*5;
```

To:

```
var shift = new Date().getTime() + 1000*60*60*5
var today = new Date(new Date(shift).toDateString()).getTime();
```

#### Reference:

- [toDateString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.